# Do not calculate if column value is 0 in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have done subtraction between two columns. If allowed amount is 0 then it should not calculate for the other columns specifically “Infusion Profit” & “Due from Pt Copay Assistance or Foundation” as mentioned in the image .
[image: o/p]
I do not know what condition should I put for the case. Please help

```
 SELECT 
                DISTINCT

    ,TMMx.ChargeCount AS Units
    ,ISNULL(TMM1.AllowedAmount,0) AS AllowedAmount  
    ,  ISNULL(TMM1.AllowedAmount,0)-CASE WHEN RC.Drug LIKE '%GAMMAPLEX%' THEN  RC.[acquisitioncost]
                      WHEN RC.Drug LIKE  '%OCTAGAM%'  THEN  RC.[acquisitioncost]
                      WHEN RC.Drug LIKE '%CARIMUNE%'  THEN  RC.[acquisitioncost]
                      WHEN RC.Drug LIKE '%PRIVIGEN%'  THEN  RC.[acquisitioncost]
                      WHEN RC.Drug LIKE '%GAMUNEX%'   THEN  RC.[acquisitioncost]
                      WHEN RC.Drug LIKE '%GAMMAGARD%'  THEN  RC.[acquisitioncost]
                      WHEN RC.Drug LIKE '%BIVIGAM%'   THEN  RC.[acquisitioncost]
                    END  *(TMMx.ChargeCount*1) -ISNULL(TMN.Sequestration,0)AS [Infusion Profit] 


                    ,  ISNULL(TMM2.PaymentAmount,0)-CASE WHEN RC.Drug LIKE'%GAMMAPLEX%' THEN  RC.[acquisitioncost]
                      WHEN RC.Drug LIKE  '%OCTAGAM%'   THEN  RC.[acquisitioncost]
                      WHEN RC.Drug LIKE '%CARIMUNE%'   THEN  RC.[acquisitioncost]
                      WHEN RC.Drug LIKE '%PRIVIGEN%'   THEN  RC.[acquisitioncost]
                      WHEN RC.Drug LIKE '%GAMUNEX%'   THEN  RC.[acquisitioncost]
                      WHEN RC.Drug LIKE '%GAMMAGARD%'   THEN  RC.[acquisitioncost]
                      WHEN RC.Drug LIKE '%BIVIGAM%'  THEN  RC.[acquisitioncost]
                    END  *(TMMx.ChargeCount*1) AS [Due from Pt Copay Assistance or Foundation]
,TM.ChargeID AS ChargeID
    FROM [TransactionMasterReport] AS TM 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT   SUM(ISNULL(ChargeCount,0)) AS ChargeCount  ,[ChargeID]
     FROM [dbo].[TransactionMasterReport]  where transactiontype='Charges'  GROUP BY [ChargeID] ) AS TMMx 
     ON TM.ChargeID=TMMx.ChargeID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[TransactionMasterReport] TMM1  
    ON TM.ChargeID=TMM1.ChargeID
    and (TMM1.TransactionType='Payments' OR TMM1.TransactionType ='Adjustments') 
    and TMM1.AllowedAmount >=1  
    and TMM1.AllowedAmount = (select   max(isnull(AllowedAmount, 0))
                           from TransactionMasterReport
                          where ChargeID = TMM1.ChargeID)
    WHERE TM.[TransactionType]='Charges' and and TM.ChargeCount !=0 
    ORDER BY  TM.[ChargeID]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your calculation in another case statement, where the outer case statement checks whether the condition is met, and if not, then set to 0...

```
CASE
    WHEN ISNULL(TMM1.AllowedAmount,0) = 0 THEN 0
    ELSE TMM1.AllowedAmount - CASE
        WHEN RC.Drug LIKE '%GAMMAPLEX%' THEN  RC.[acquisitioncost]
        WHEN RC.Drug LIKE  '%OCTAGAM%'  THEN  RC.[acquisitioncost]
        WHEN RC.Drug LIKE '%CARIMUNE%'  THEN  RC.[acquisitioncost]
        WHEN RC.Drug LIKE '%PRIVIGEN%'  THEN  RC.[acquisitioncost]
        WHEN RC.Drug LIKE '%GAMUNEX%'   THEN  RC.[acquisitioncost]
        WHEN RC.Drug LIKE '%GAMMAGARD%'  THEN  RC.[acquisitioncost]
        WHEN RC.Drug LIKE '%BIVIGAM%'   THEN  RC.[acquisitioncost]
    END * (TMMx.ChargeCount*1)
    - ISNULL(TMN.Sequestration,0)
END AS [Infusion Profit]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
case when ISNULL(TMM1.AllowedAmount,0)=0 then 
    WhatYouWant (possible 0 or null) 
else calculate as FieldName 
end
```